# CMap with CArray Inside it

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a `typedef` struct like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    int id;
    CString name;
} USER_NAME;

CMap<int,int, CArray<USER_NAME>, CArray<USER_NAME>> * m_mUserNameMap;
```

In the CPP file:

```
CArray<USER_NAME> sUName;
sUName.id = 10;
sUName.name = "Test it!!!";

m_mUserNameMap = new CMap<int,int, CArray<USER_NAME>, CArray<USER_NAME>>;

m_mUserNameMap->SetAt(1, sUName);
```

I am getting following error:

> error C2248: 'CObject::CObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'

No idea what's going on!! Any help is welcome.

I tried making `m_mUserNameMap` not a pointer and that gives the above error in that line itself.

Comment: Hint: stop using old MFC containers and use std containers such as `std::map` and `std::vector`.

Comment: First, use references for the `ARG_` template parameters like `CMap<int,int&, CArray<USER_NAME>, CArray<USER_NAME>&>` because `CObject`'s  constructors are private and second - use `std::map` and `std::vector`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a `CMap` requires the value type to be copy-constructible and assignable but these operations are marked as private for `CObject`-derived classes such as `CArray`. That is why you get that error message.

You can't declare the map like you're attempting. What you can do is have the value type as a pointer. So then you'll add the address of the array to the map and not the array itself which would expect a copy.

```
CMap<int, int, CArray<USER_NAME> *, CArray<USER_NAME> *> *m_mUserNameMap;
```

However, ask yourself if you really must use MFC containers because the standard containers are an alternative that don't suffer from these limitations. Use MFC containers only if they're the obvious choice and make complete sense in the context of GUI code. Otherwise rely on the standard containers.

```
std::map<int, std::vector<USER_NAME>> *m_mUserNameMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

> However, ask yourself if you really must use MFC containers

I myself would say, yes. MFC is much preferred over standard lib. Two reasons:

---One example:
YouTube video: C++Now 2018: Z. Laine “Boost.Text: Fixing std::string, and Adding Unicode to Standard C++ (part 1)”
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=944GjKxwMBo
    --std::string is very inefficient, apparently. Also, it seems like the standard library suffers from lack of dedicated support... If they get around to fixing it, they will. Much like what happens in the Linux world.

---Another reason:
Forum thread posted in www.cplusplus.com:
        Linux developers threaten to pull “kill switch”
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/lounge/243067/
   --While Linux is not the standard library... they are all open source resources... Too close for comfort, IMO.